# Install libreoffice 4.0.1

Tags: installation, libreoffice

I'm using ubuntu 12.10, and i'm trying to install Libre office 4.0.1 but cant find anything about who to install it after you have downloaded the file. How do you install the tar.gz file after the download?

Answer (score 1):

You mean the RC1 of 4.0.1, right?
You can get the steps here: http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/installation/linux/

To summarise, you need to remove all the libreoffice packages presently in the system (easiest is using Synaptic)
Extract the tar.gz
Install using sudo dpkg -i *.deb from inside the DEB folder and desktop-integration folders.